# Create a button that can add number in a queue?

Tags: c#, queue

How to create a button that can add number in a
queue?
usually i only declare a number but what i want is to create a button that can add number in a queue look like increment

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class QueueExample 
{
static void Main()
{
    Queue<string> msgs = new Queue<string>();

    msgs.Enqueue("Message 1");
    msgs.Enqueue("Message 2");
    msgs.Enqueue("Message 3");
    msgs.Enqueue("Message 4");
    msgs.Enqueue("Message 5");

    Console.WriteLine(msgs.Dequeue());
    Console.WriteLine(msgs.Peek());
    Console.WriteLine(msgs.Peek());

    Console.WriteLine();

    foreach(string msg in msgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Looks like a Console application....! it is not possible to create a button inside it. Its unclear that what you are asking and trying to achieve, it would be great if you add more explanations about the things that you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for that., but my concern is how can i create a button that can add number in a queue?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a console application you cannot create a button here instead for that you can do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Queue before adding new element");
foreach (string msg in msgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}

Console.WriteLine("Enter Something to the queue");
msgs.Enqueue(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Queue before adding new element");
foreach (string msg in msgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Which will prompt the user to enter something and it will add that to the queue